# RecyclerView adapter doesnt execute any methods

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

*I am working on a simple project. I am trying to show list of data but in adapter none of the methods are called*

```
class PlacnikiAdapter(private val placniki: List<Placnik>) : 
RecyclerView.Adapter<PlacnikiAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val textView: TextView

    init {
        // Define click listener for the ViewHolder's View.
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.ime)
    }
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.layout_rv_item, 
viewGroup, false)

    return ViewHolder(inflater)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.textView.text = placniki[position].ime

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return placniki.size
}

class PlacnikiFragment : Fragment() {

private val TAG = "PlacnikiFragment"
private lateinit var binding: PlacnikiFragmentBinding
lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
private val retrofitService = RetrofitService.getInstance()

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Defines the xml file for the fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.placniki_fragment, container, false)
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding = PlacnikiFragmentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    //get viewmodel instance using MyViewModelFactory
    viewModel =
        ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelFactory(Repository(retrofitService))).get(
            MainViewModel::class.java
        )
    //set recyclerview adapter

    viewModel.placnikiList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        Log.d(TAG, "placnikiList: $it")
        binding.recyclerview.adapter = PlacnikiAdapter(it)
    })
    viewModel.errorMessage.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        Log.d(TAG, "errorMessage: $it")
    })
    viewModel.getVsiPlacniki()
}
```

*I dont know what could be causing this. I changed activity to a fragment and beforehand everything worked normally and after changing to fragment recyclerview isnt showing items and the list isnt empty either so i dont pass list of zero items*

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the problem was in data binding. I had to add below code in gradle module
`buildFeatures{dataBinding = true}`